# FileNotFound after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, capistrano, rails-activestorage

I'm working with simple rails 6 application and use active storage with Amazon S3, it works fine. But after I deploy anything all of my pic URLs have 500 errors. But my attachments still in the database and all my pictures stay untouched on S3 and URLs to `rails/active_storage/representations` are the very same before deploy when all was fine.

All credentials are encrypted in credentials.yml.enc and master.key in the config folder and if rails can start and upload a file into s3 in this way it works fine?

Here how I display picture, nothing special:

```
image_tag @product.images.first.variant(resize: "420x")
```

I guess it's something with some secret tokens which augmentates application but couldn't find anything relevant. Can someone advise at least where can be a problem?

Comment: So, just to be clear, you are saying that when you inspect the URL in the deployed app, it is trying to reach the images with a URL that does properly link to the image in S3, but still will not display the image, is that correct?

Comment: Maybe yr s3 url is not public make sure